# signlar hub method termination

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'd like to know if an Hub method called from js client is 
executed completely also if client disconnected during execution

For example..

```
public virtual void Join(int userId)
{
    using (var context = new HubConnectionContext(this, RoomId, userId))
    {
        T workflow = GetWorkflow(context);
        workflow.OnUserJoin();    
    }                                      

}
```

I can be sure that the Dispose Method of HubConnectionContext is called also if client disconnect during using block?

Comment: Calling Dispose isn't actually related to your question. If you get into the using block the Dispose will always be called, whatever the case. So do you want to know about Dispose in using or about the more generic situation?

Comment: i'd like to know if dispose is ensured.. as always.. and if there as some code after dispose block, are executed also with communication interrupted